# Attempt to display prompt until correct entry is entered in using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make "Enter your Password: " prompt appear until the correct password is entered. There is no limit to the attempts of password entry. So far I came up with this code using Javascript

```js
    function promptPassword() {

      var name = prompt("Enter your Username: ");
      var pwd = prompt("Enter your Password: ");

      if (pwd == 'P@ssw0rd') {
        alert("Password is correct, you are allowed to enter the site");
      }

      while (pwd != 'P@ssw0rd') {
        alert("Login is incorrect");
        prompt("Enter your Password: ");
      }

    }
```

```html
<body onload="promptPassword();">
  </body>
```

When I enter the correct password in first attempt the correct alert displays and it goes away when I click 'ok', which is expected.
When I type wrong passwords it keeps prompting to enter the password again, which is also as expected. 
But the problem here is when I first enter wrong password and then enter right password in the next attempts, it still keeps prompting to enter the password again. Once the correct password is entered, "Password is correct, you are allowed to enter the site" alert should display and should go away, when 'ok' is clicked

Comment: There is the assignment to 'pwd' missing in your second prompt() call

Comment: You are not re-assigning the value to `pwd`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your prompt return value isn't being assigned in the while loop. Try this:

```
function promptPassword( )
{

var name = prompt ("Enter your Username: ");
var pwd = prompt ("Enter your Password: ");

while (pwd != 'P@ssw0rd'){
alert("Login is incorrect");
pwd = prompt ("Enter your Password: ");
}

alert("Password is correct, you are allowed to enter the site");

}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried this the prompt does not appear anymore. But still I need to see the alert "Password is correct, you are allowed to enter the site". But when I enter the correct password in the second attempt I don't see that alert

Comment: You'd need to put the alert("Password is correct") after the while loop. I've updated my answer.

Comment: You need to run function after init it. like promptPassword().
+1 for answer but anyone can see this script by see source code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `pwd` to `prompt("Enter your password: ");`. If you don't, it will keep asking you, but the password variable will never update, and you'll be stuck in the loop forever!

```js
function promptPassword( )
{
    
    var name = prompt ("Enter your Username: ");
    var pwd = prompt ("Enter your Password: ");
    
    while (pwd != 'P@ssw0rd'){
        alert("Login is incorrect");
        pwd = prompt ("Enter your Password: ");
    }
    
    alert("Password is correct, you are allowed to enter the site");
    
}
promptPassword();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried this the prompt does not appear anymore. But still I need to see the alert "Password is correct, you are allowed to enter the site". But when I enter the correct password in the second attempt I don't see that alert

Comment: Ah, well then you need to add that too. Fixin' it!

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy

Answer (score -1):

```
enter code here function promptPassword( )
```

{

```
var name = prompt ("Enter your Username: ");
var pwd = prompt ("Enter your Password: ");

while (pwd != 'P@ssw0rd'){
    alert("Login is incorrect");
    pwd = prompt ("Enter your Password: ");
}

alert("Password is correct, you are allowed to enter the site");
while ( name != "Youssef" ) {      alert("Login is incorrect");
    name = prompt ("Enter your Username: ");
} } promptPassword();
```

Comment: Please copy and paste onto your console (ctrl + shift + j) (copy all code)

Comment: New code :function promptPassword( )
{
    
    var name = prompt ("Enter your Username: ");
    var pwd = prompt ("Enter your Password: ");
    
    while (pwd != 'P@ssw0rd'){
        alert("Login is incorrect");
        pwd = prompt ("Enter your Password: ");
    }
    
    alert("Password is correct, you are allowed to enter the site");
    while ( name != "Youssef" ) {      alert("Login is incorrect");
        name = prompt ("Enter your Username: ");
    }
}
promptPassword();